Converting date and time into static data
Similar questions have been asked, but I do not get it: How may I transform the \statictime into a string, that cannot be changed?
%transformations of \time
\newcount\hour  %
\newcount\hours  %
\newcount\minute  %
\newcount\second  %
\hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
\hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
\minute=\time
\advance \minute by -\hours
\def\statictime{
\the\day.\the\month.\the\year\ \the\hour:\ifnum\the\minute<10 0\fi\the\minute}
\def\currenttime{
\the\day.\the\month.\the\year\ \the\hour:\ifnum\the\minute<10 0\fi\the\minute}

\statictime \ This should not be updated

\currenttime\ This should be updated
\bye


Replace \def with \edef?

What does mean "a string which cannot be changed"? Each TeX run the time is different. If you want a "static string", you can look at your clock and then write (for example) \def\statictime{19.11.2024 9:55}

@wipet
:-)  One thousand different \statictime(s)...

@wipet Please don't bother, this might be an unsolvable circle.

This is simply unsolvable because you didn't exactly say what data have to be stored to the \statictime macro.

Use \edef. But you should note that TeX doesn't “keep the clock running”: the values of \year, \month, \day and \time are always the same as when the TeX run started, unless you manually change them.
%transformations of \time
\newcount\hour
\newcount\hours
\newcount\minute

\def\computetime{%
  \hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
  \hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
  \minute=\time
  \advance \minute by -\hours
}
\computetime
\edef\statictime{%
  \the\day.\the\month.\the\year\ \the\hour:\ifnum\the\minute<10 0\fi\the\minute}
\def\currenttime{%
  \the\day.\the\month.\the\year\ \the\hour:\ifnum\the\minute<10 0\fi\the\minute}

\statictime \ This should not be updated

\day=25
\month=12
\year=2026
\time=588
\computetime

\currenttime\ This should be updated

\bye



Sorry, again, I was not clear enough. \currenttime shall always show the actual date and time, \statictime shall show the date and time inserted at a past time and shall not be changed in the future or manually.  I know, this is a kind of circle, that might be unsolvable .

@MBE Just hardwire the date in the document and mark it “DON'T TOUCH”. It is, in principle, possible to access the “birthdate” of the file, but it's heavily system dependent.
